# How to natively execute AVI vídeos in Chromium?

Tags: compilation, chromium, avi

I need to execute AVI vídeos in Chromium natively.

I've already seen that there are some plugins to do that, but it's not the case. As I said before, I must execute AVI files natively, i.e., without any plugin.

I've already made some customizations in Chromium source code and compiled it, but all of them was too simple.

Is it too difficult to implement that customization?? Where can I find some information about this?

Comment: Have you tried compiling Chromium with these two flags: ``ffmpeg_branding = "Chrome"


proprietary_codecs = true``?

Comment: Yeah, @Asesh! Unfortunately it didn't work. Do you have any other idea?